# Javascript - How can I display the value of an array above a form?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I currently have a form that uses alert as a means of showing error. Instead I would like it to print the errors just above the inputs devices so that users can refer to it. This is my current code for showing errors:

```
function showErrors() {
    if (errList.length >= 1)
    alert(errList.join("\n"));
}
```

here is a jsfiddle for the rest of the code: https://jsfiddle.net/rvomhauo/

The place I would like to print the errors is here: http://imgur.com/0Ss32so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You pretty much just need to create an element that will "host" the error messages. Instead of `alert`, set the contents of that element to be the string of errors. Something like

```
<div id="errors"></div>

function showErrors () {
  document.getElementById('errors').innerHTML = errList.join('<br/>')
}
```

And, of course, place this element in the desired location as depicted in your image example.

Answer (score 0):

Add somewhere to show the errors in your html

```
<td id="errors"></td>
```

and adjust showErrors to put them in the page

```
function showErrors() {
    if (errList.length >= 1) {
       errors = errList.join("\n");
      e = document.createElement('p');
      document.getElementById("errors")
      .appendChild(e);
     }
}
```

Comment: If you use this answer, make sure to set the contents of `e` to be the `errors` String.